# Internal Server Error because one cookie is too big

Tags: magento, cookies, magento-1.9, internal-server-error

I don't know the reason but _GPSLSC cookie gets very big after some time we browse our Magento ecommerce, so sometimes we get a Internal Server Error and then I have to delete the cookie. How can I fix it so it won't happen again? Is it a chrome related issue?
Thanks

Comment: Server administration error - mod_pagespeed - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85583/internal-server-error-because-one-cookie-is-too-big

Answer (score 0):

In my case Magento in Ubuntu 14 LTS, nginx, hhvm with php5-fpm for a specific service, i was reading in /var/log/hhvm/error.log

```
nFatal error: Stack overflow in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php on line 977
```

In this case was a conflict between hhvm and php5-fpm.
Shut down php5-fpm and retest it.

or

In case you have only hhvm just remove local_storage_cache from

```
pagespeed EnableFilters
```

and add the following line below EnableFilters

```
pagespeed DisableFilters local_storage_cache;
```